# invoking bash with the -t option

Tags: bash

Can anyone tell me about the `-t` option when invoking bash?

I found the following  handy command to use a [lightweight terminal window as an application launcher](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Urxvt#Use_urxvt_as_application_launcher)

```
urxvt -geometry 80x3 -name 'bashrun' -e sh -c "/bin/bash -i -t"
```

Through a little investigation of its behavior, I see that the `-t` essentially makes bash exit after executing one command, but I am curious if there is any more to that specific `-t` option. I can't actually find any documentation about it, and I've looked through the following docs:

- `man bash`
- [Invoking Bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Invoking-Bash.html)
- [standard bash options](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/standard-options.html)

I find it odd that `-t` is not as clearly laid out as the rest of the options.

Comment: Side note: `bash --help` actually tells you to use `help set` to see descriptions for short options.

Answer (score 5):

You are right that it is amazingly poorly documented.  What documentation that there is is quite simple:

```
-t      Exit after reading and executing one command.
```

The bash source code is available [here](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/).  I looked at version 4.2.  The short flags handled by bash are listed in `flags.c` and in there is the relevant line:

```
{ 't', &just_one_command },
```

So, `-t` on the command line sets the variable `just_one_command`.  This variable is used in just one place: it occurs in an `if` condition at the end of a loop in `eval.c`:

```
  if (just_one_command)
    EOF_Reached = EOF;
```

In other words, if the `-t` flag is given, then, after the first command is executed, the end-of-file condition is signaled and `bash` exits.

#### MORE DETAIL

From `eval.c`, command line execution in `bash` appears to be controlled by the function `reader_loop`:

```
reader_loop ()
{
  int our_indirection_level;
  COMMAND * volatile current_command;
  USE_VAR(current_command);
  current_command = (COMMAND *)NULL;
  our_indirection_level = ++indirection_level;
  while (EOF_Reached == 0)
    {
      int code;
      code = setjmp_nosigs (top_level);

      [ ... Much code removed ... ]

      if (just_one_command)
        EOF_Reached = EOF;
    }
  indirection_level--;
  return (last_command_exit_value);
}
```

The loop inside `reader_loop` continues until it receives the signal `EOF_Reached`.  The sole effect of the `-t` option is to set this flag at the end of loop which assures that the loop is executed only once.

Comment: Thanks all for the responses. Im marking @John1024's answer since it includes the original source code for the option. It seems I needed to look in `help set` for the actual documenation

Comment: @HariSeldon if you should come back, please use the tick mark to accept this answer.

Answer (score 5):

Using the `bash` builtin `help`, i.e. by saying `help set`, you'd find:

```
  -t  Exit after reading and executing one command.
```

Since `bash` parses a line at a time, you might have multiple commands separated by `;` on the same line and those would execute.  For example, the following:

```
set -t; echo Do something; echo do more; echo and more
echo no more
```

would produce

```
Do something
do more
and more
```

as the output.  On the other hand, the following:

```
set -t
echo Do something
echo do more
echo and more
echo no more
```

would **not** produce any output.

---

You could look for the documentation in the `info` page.  Say:

```
info bash "Shell Builtin Commands"
```

Navigate to `* Bourne Shell Builtins::` and search for `help`.

Comment: `help set` seems to be what i needed. Where is it listed that `help set` is something to look for? I'm not being snide, i am genuinely curious. Looking through `man bash` again, I am not seeing any mention of it.

Comment: @HariSeldon I usually refer to `info` pages instead of manuals for those are usually more detailed.  Please refer to the edit above for finding help on `help`.

Answer (score 2):

It is explained in the man page, just difficult to find.

The options not mentioned in the "OPTIONS" block at the beginning are options for `set` which can be given as options to bash, too:

> The options can also be specified as arguments to an invocation of the shell.

```
-t      Exit after reading and executing one command.
```